# Why was the Snow White's father called the First King

Tags: names, disney, disney-princess

On the Disney Wiki, Snow White’s father, the King, is called “The *First* King.” One Wiki commentator thinks it’s an awkward title and asked would it make more sense for him to be called that if he died and Snow White’s mother remarried. I think it’s awkward too, because how could the Wiki specifically say “First” if there were no kings after him and we all know the Evil Queen ruled the kingdom alone.

So why *was* he called the *First* King?

Comment: There doesn't have to be more kings after the first for a king to be called the _first_ King, there just has to be none who were King before. I don't understand the premise of your question.

Comment: What I mean is wouldn’t it have made more sense if he died and Snow White’s mother remarried, thus making her second husband the SECOND King?

Comment: ..because a wiki is a fan-maintained encyclopaedia, and can literally say whatever the fans write. Your premise seems to be that wiki is *canon*. This is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: No because he’s the first king regardless if she remarried.

Comment: maybe a better question would be "why does the wiki say he's the first king"

Comment: Think in aspirational terms. Even if she's remarkably long-lived, one can hope someone else will eventually come to the throne; and eventually that someone would be a guy.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mentions of Snow White's father, The King in some of the earlier [(1949)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEeqPktb-5E) and [(1952)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAwun7bY5MQ) Little Golden books and in the [1952 Chinese film tie-in book](http://filmic-light.blogspot.com/2017/03/chinese-snow-white-book.html) and the 1951 [The Complete Story of Walt Disney's Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6431023-the-complete-story-of-walt-disney-s-snow-white-and-the-seven-dwarfs).  In each of them he's referred to as

> "**The King**" (or "**the lonely King**" since his wife is dead).

rather than the

> "***First*** King"

[image]

and

[image]

and

[image]

It would appear that calling him the First King is simply an invention of the [original wiki entry writer, Whatdouwant](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/The_First_King_(Snow_White)?oldid=649476).

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I read this, I assumed "First King" might be a reference to him being the first King, in the first full length Disney film?